# Absolute position breaks the list elements into new line

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, css-position

I am trying to customize navigation menu in wordpress. I want my submenu to appear below the parent menu element in a single line. I am also setting submenu position to absolute so that I can control the overlap of main menu bar and submenu bar.

Below is my minimized CSS (in SASS, for clarity I am posting only those portions that i thought relevant).

Problem: Everything is working fine except the submenu items now break into lines, rather than in a single line.

Observation: If I remove absolute positioning OR I give a fixed width, then it works.

What I tried: Putting white-space: nowrap and display:inline-block (in li), though I know display doesn't make sense for absolute positioning.

```
.menu-primary-menu-container {
    &>ul {
        float:left;
        list-style: none;
        &>li {
            position: relative;
            float:left;
            &>ul {
                position: absolute;
                height: 40px;
                bottom: -30px;
                list-style: none;

                &>li {
                    float:left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a width to the submenu in order to get it working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1grq7on6/)

```
.menu-primary-menu-container {
    &>ul {
        float:left;
        list-style: none;
        &>li {
            position: relative;
            float:left;
            &>ul {
                position: absolute;
                height: 40px;
                bottom: -30px;
                list-style: none;
                width: 500px;

                &>li {
                    float:left;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you use `position: absolute;` without a width or without specify `left` **and** `right`, the element will use the width as small as possible.

Comment: interesting ... it indeed try to use as small width as possible ... but I don't want to fix width for menu (as it would depend on number of items) .. is there any other way (left:0 doesn't work)

Comment: As I already said: if you use `left`, you **also need** to set `right`.